# Purpose of the outer extra parenthese on JavaScript closure function

Tags: javascript, closures

What is the purpose of the outer extra parentheses on the below JavaScript closure function?  I have been told in other posts that they are not strictly necessary, but they're a convention to make it clear that the result of the function is being passed, not the function itself.  The below quote from http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html
, however, conflicts.  Which is correct?

> Notice the () around the anonymous function. This is required by the
>   language, since statements that begin with the token function are
>   always considered to be function declarations. Including () creates a
>   function expression instead.

```
(function () {
    // ... all vars and functions are in this scope only
    // still maintains access to all globals
}());
```

Comment: You can also prefix it with void or an arithmetic operator.

Comment: @Jack.  Please elaberate.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: void function() { dostuff(); }();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that different engines have different ways of interpreting

`function(){...}();`

so the most popular and accepted way to make it clear, to all engines, is to group the code in parentheses.

`(function(){...}());`

At the same time, what you quoted makes a very interesting point. A function expression might go:

`var f = function() {...}`

Whereas a function declaration looks like:

`function f() {...}`

You see how it's easy/convenient for the parser to tell the difference by looking at the first token?

```
IF TOKEN1 EQ "function": FXN DECLARATION
ELSE: FXN EXPRESSION
```

But it wouldn't make sense for your (immediately-invoked) function to be a function declaration (it's not going to be re-used, you don't want to have it hoisted, or in the namespace, etc.) so adding some innocuous parentheses is a good way of indicating that it's a function expression.

Comment: So, it is sometimes required and sometimes not based on the given engine, and I should just do it all the time?

Comment: Yeah. It's a very strong convention. You should probably do it all the time... unless you find some other popular way to make it clear to the engine, and want to champion that.

Comment: FF results in s syntax error without it.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I must clear up:

```
(function () {

}());
```

is equivalent for

```
(function () {

})();
```

and also for (Backbone.js uses it)

```
(function(){

}).call(this);
```

Second, if you're going to use it that way, then it's not an anonymous/closure function. its **Immediately-Invoked Function expression**

it would act as a closure (because it won't be *immediately-invoked*) if you assign its returned context to a variable. This kinda useful if you need a static class (when properties and methods could be accessed without instantiation). For example:

```
var stuff = (function(){

    // AGAIN: its not an IIFE in this case

    function foo() // <- public method
    {
        alert('Jeeez');
    }

    return {
       foo : foo,
    }
})();


stuff.foo(); //Alerts Jeeez
```

> What is the purpose of the outer extra parentheses on the below
>   JavaScript closure function?

The purpose isn't usual and quite strange - its all about function arguments.
For example,

```
(function(window, document){ // <- you see this? 2 "arguments"

  alert(arguments.length); // 0!

})();
```

but if we pass them to that outer parentheses

```
(function(/* So its not for arguments */ ){

  alert(arguments.length); // 2

})(window, document); // <- Instead we pass arguments here
```

Comment: Great explanation.  I wish I can vote more.  I believe other answers better met my specific question, but this clarified a bigger mystery of mine.  `(function (c, d) {console.log(a,b,c,d);}(a, b));` will display a,b,a,b.  I get it thanks to you!  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The extra surrounding parentheses disambiguate a function expression from a regular function declaration.

Though the extra parentheses are standard practice, the same thing can be achieved by doing this instead:

```
void function() {
    // do stuff
}();
```

Or, even:

```
+function() {
    // do stuff
}();
```

Though, out of these two alternatives, I prefer the `void` notation because in most cases we don't really care about the return value of an immediate invocation.

Other places where the parentheses aren't required is when an expression is expected:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    return function() {
        alert('hello');
    }
}(), 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

They are necessary because the parser goes in the function declaration mode when it sees

```
function
```

in a *statement context*.

After `function` token, it is expecting a name for the function because a function declaration must include a name for the function. But instead of a name it sees `(` instead, so it's a syntax error.

I think, it could backtrack and unambiguously just treat it as a function expression but it doesn't.

---

`var module = XXX`

In the above, `XXX` is in *expression context*, if a `function` appears there, it is treated as a start of a function expression. Function expressions don't have to have
a name for the function, so it's not a syntax error to have `(` appear right after `function`.

So you can write:

```
var module = function(){}();
```

But not

```
function(){}()
```

You can use many tricks to make the above an expression:

```
(XXX)
!XXX
~XXX
+XXX

//This doesn't work however:
{YYY} //the braces are delimiting a block, and inside block you start in
      //a statement context
```

`XXX` is in expression context because it's enclosed by parenthesis or is following a unary operator, therefore any function substituted for `XXX` is a function expression.